# Checking file's existence by name in a GCS bucket with Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to know if Google Cloud Storage provides an efficient way of checking if a file with a given name exists in a given bucket with node.js. A method such as `bucket.fileExists('someName')` would be ideal. I apologize if there's an obvious answer. Any constructive feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They added the `file.exists()` [method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File#exists).

```
const fileExists = _=>{
    return file.exists().then((data)=>{ console.log(data[0]); });
}

fileExists();
//logs a boolean to the console;
//true if the file exists;
//false if the file doesn't exist.
```